# Почему Retrofit не шлет запрос по https?

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit2

Падает `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
При этом запрашиваемый домен домен имеет верифицированный сертификат. 
Если бы речь шла о self-signed сертификате, то причина была бы ясна.

Объясните, что нужно делать чтобы можно было послать запрос на "нормальный" (верифицированный) домен?

**UPDATE:**

Так создается инстанс ретрофита:

```
init {
    App.getComponent().inject(this)
    val builder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().socketFactory(getSSLConfig(App.getContext()).socketFactory)
    builder.addInterceptor(httpInterceptor)
    val client = builder.build()
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(Net.BASE_URL.value)
            .client(client)
            .build()
}

@Throws(CertificateException::class, IOException::class, KeyStoreException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, KeyManagementException::class)
private fun getSSLConfig(context: Context): SSLContext {

    // Loading CAs from an InputStream
    var cf: CertificateFactory? = null
    cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")

    var ca: Certificate? = null
    // I'm using Java7. If you used Java6 close it manually with finally.
    context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.certificate_ca).use({ cert -> ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert) })

    // Creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
    keyStore.load(null, null)
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)

    // Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore.
    val tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
    val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
    tmf.init(keyStore)

    // Creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.trustManagers, null)

    return sslContext
}
```

При обращении к серверу получаю `Handshake failed`. Что я делаю не верно?

**Stacktrace:**

```
01-19 12:50:46.578 7161-7161/ru.rst.console W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
01-19 12:50:46.579 7161-7161/ru.rst.console W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:423)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
01-19 12:50:46.580 7161-7161/ru.rst.console W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                              at ru.rst.console.base.http.HttpInterceptor.handleResponse(HttpInterceptor.kt:29)
                                                              at ru.rst.console.base.http.HttpInterceptor.intercept(HttpInterceptor.kt:25)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                              at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
                                                              at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
01-19 12:50:46.582 7161-7161/ru.rst.console W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                          Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xa5522bc0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                          error:10000066:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_ALERT (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:465 0xa3078e9f:0x00000000)
                                                              at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
01-19 12:50:46.583 7161-7161/ru.rst.console W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:351)
                                                            ... 27 more
```

**UPDATE-2:**
На сервере используется node.js (express.js), при старте ему на вход подается `{key: privateKey, cert: certificate (Сертификат в формате x509 (.PEM))}`. В nginx так же прописаны пути к этим файлам:

```
ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /application/builds/rootCA.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /application/builds/rootCA.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers  "HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';
```

А в android, в коде что я привел:

```
context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.certificate_ca).use({ cert -> ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert) })
```

`R.raw.certificate_ca` - это корневой сертификат.

Comment: Кем издан доменный сертификат? Кроме того, что он не self-signed нужно чтобы корневой сертификат CA, который выдал доменный сертификат, был загружен в системный keystore Android.

Comment: @eugeneek Сертификат от AlphaSSL, куплен на reg.ru. Я так и сделал (обновил вопрос), теперь появилась ошибка `Handshake failed`. Я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: По коду вроде всё нормально. Видимо что-то не так с самим сертификатом. Может он выдан не на тот домен, на котором используется? Ещё добавьте полный стек-трейс ошибки

Comment: @eugeneek приложил stacktrace

Comment: Попробуйте указать версию TLSv1.2 при создании ssl context: `SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");`

Comment: И передайте SecureRandom вместо null при инициализации `sslContext.init(null, tmf.trustManagers, new SecureRandom());`

Comment: И укажите на всех ли версия ОС падает. Вроде видел такое только на 4.4.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, @eugeneek, тестил на 7 и 8 Android, та же ошибка`SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x92ba95c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:10000066:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_ALERT (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:465 0xa3078e9f:0x00000000)`

Comment: А через какой нибудь рест клиент попробуйте запрос сделать. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) например.

Comment: @eugeneek через postman работает

Comment: @eugeneek добавил в вопрос пояснение того что на сервере, может это натолкнет вас на мысль

Comment: @sanu0074, если через Postman работает и вы там при запросе сертификаты никакие не прикрепляете, то попробуйте также и на андроиде сделать - т.е. никаких сертификатов не прикреплять и просто как обычно отправить запрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб изначально я так и делал и это вызывало ошибку `CertPathValidatorException : Trust anchor for certificate path not found`

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("http://")
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
      .build();

public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)   {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            builder.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: вы не поняли суть вопроса, мне не нужна заглушка, мне нужно понять как заставить его работать с моим сертификатом